# android IndexOutOfBoundsException on GridView click

Tags: android, gridview

I have list_id_emp.xml in asset folder:

```
<employees>
<emp id="01">
    <name>jame</name>
    <department>Development</department>
</emp>
<emp id="02">
    <name>natalie</name>
    <department>Testing</department>
</emp>
<emp id="03">
    <name>phil</name>
    <department>Testing</department>
</emp>
```

this is list_dettail_emp.xml in asset folder:

```
<employees_detail>
<emp_detail id_detail="01">
    <name>jame</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <email>jame@gmail.com</email>
</emp_detail>
<emp_detail id_detail="02">
    <name>natalie</name>
    <age>27</age>
    <gender>female</gender>
    <email>natalie@gmail.com</email>
</emp_detail>
<emp_detail id_detail="03">
    <name>phil</name>
    <age>40</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <email>phil@gmail.com</email>
</emp_detail>
```

this is code in Activity :

```
GridView gv_id;
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_DEPARTMENT = "department";
List<HashMap<String, String>> empHashmap;
List<ClassIdEmp> empList = null;

static final String KEY_DETAIL_ID = "id_detail";
static final String KEY_DETAIL_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_DETAIL_AGE = "age";
static final String KEY_DETAIL_GENDER = "gender";
static final String KEY_DETAIL_EMAIL = "email";
List<HashMap<String, String>> empdetailHashmap;
List<ClassDetailEmp> empdetailList = null;

String age_detail, email_detail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_idemp);

    gv_id = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvId);

    try {
        XmlPullParserIdEmp parser_id_emp = new XmlPullParserIdEmp();
        empList = parser_id_emp.parse(getAssets().open("list_id_emp.xml"));
        BinderDataIdEmp bd_id_emp = new BinderDataIdEmp(IdEmp.this, empHashmap);
        gv_id.setAdapter(bd_id_emp);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    gv_id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // get id from list_id_emp.xml
            String id_emp = empHashmap.get(position).get(KEY_ID);

            try {
                XmlPullParserDetailEmp parserDetailEmp = new XmlPullParserDetailEmp();
                // use id from list_id_emp.xml for parse list_detail_emp.xml
                empdetailList = parserDetailEmp.parse(getAssets().open("list_detail_emp.xml"), id_emp);

                age_detail = empdetailHashmap.get(position).get(KEY_DETAIL_AGE);
                email_detail = empdetailHashmap.get(position).get(KEY_DETAIL_EMAIL);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), age_detail + ":" + email_detail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

// XmlPullPaser for parse list_id_emp.xml
public class XmlPullParserIdEmp {

    private ClassIdEmp c;
    private String text;

    public XmlPullParserIdEmp() {
        empList = new ArrayList<ClassIdEmp>();
    }

    public List<ClassIdEmp> parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;

        try {
            empHashmap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            HashMap<String,String> map = null;

            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        String id = parser.getAttributeValue(null, KEY_ID);
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("emp")) {
                            c = new ClassIdEmp();
                            map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                            c.setId(id);
                            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("emp")) {
                            empList.add(c);
                            empHashmap.add(map);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME)) {
                            c.setName(text);
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, text);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DEPARTMENT)) {
                            c.setDepartment(text);
                            map.put(KEY_DEPARTMENT, text);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return empList;
    }
}

// XmlPullPaser for parse list_detail_emp.xml
public class XmlPullParserDetailEmp {

    private ClassDetailEmp c_d;
    private String text;

    boolean checkId = false;

    public XmlPullParserDetailEmp() {
        empdetailList = new ArrayList<ClassDetailEmp>();
    }

    public List<ClassDetailEmp> parse(InputStream is, String id_emp) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;

        try {
            empdetailHashmap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            HashMap<String,String> map = null;

            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        String id_detail = parser.getAttributeValue(null, KEY_DETAIL_ID);
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("emp_detail")) {
                            c_d = new ClassDetailEmp();
                            map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                            c_d.setId(id_detail);
                            map.put(KEY_DETAIL_ID, id_detail);
                            if (id_detail.contains(id_emp)) {
                                checkId = true;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("emp_detail")) {
                            if (checkId == true){
                                empdetailList.add(c_d);
                                empdetailHashmap.add(map);
                                checkId = false;
                            }
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DETAIL_NAME)) {
                            c_d.setName(text);
                            map.put(KEY_DETAIL_NAME, text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DETAIL_AGE)) {
                            c_d.setName(text);
                            map.put(KEY_DETAIL_AGE, text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DETAIL_GENDER)) {
                            c_d.setName(text);
                            map.put(KEY_DETAIL_GENDER, text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DETAIL_EMAIL)) {
                            c_d.setName(text);
                            map.put(KEY_DETAIL_EMAIL, text);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return empdetailList;
    }
}
```

this is result :
[image]

when I click position 1, Toast will show result like image.
but when click position 2 & 3, Toast don't show anything,
and I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1.
how to fix it ?

update
this is logcat:

```
07-18 11:04:24.319 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
07-18 11:04:24.319 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-18 11:04:24.319 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-18 11:04:24.323 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at noname.test3.IdEmp$1.onItemClick(IdEmp.java:71)
07-18 11:04:24.323 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-18 11:04:24.323 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
07-18 11:04:24.323 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
07-18 11:04:24.323 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
07-18 11:04:24.323 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-18 11:04:24.327 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 11:04:24.327 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 11:04:24.335 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-18 11:04:24.335 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:04:24.335 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 11:04:24.335 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-18 11:04:24.339 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-18 11:04:24.339 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 11:04:26.507 10783-10787/noname.test3 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 4% free 8309K/8647K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 11ms
07-18 11:04:26.827 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-18 11:04:31.023 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at noname.test3.IdEmp$1.onItemClick(IdEmp.java:71)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-18 11:04:47.403 10783-10783/noname.test3 W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is BinderDataIdEmp:

```
public class BinderDataIdEmp extends BaseAdapter {

static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_DEPARTMENT = "department";
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<HashMap<String,String>> empHashmap;
ViewHolder holder;

public BinderDataIdEmp(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {

    this.empHashmap = map;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return empHashmap.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_id, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv_id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv8Id);
        holder.tv_name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv8Name);
        holder.tv_department = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv8Department);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_id.setText(empHashmap.get(position).get(KEY_ID));
    holder.tv_name.setText(empHashmap.get(position).get(KEY_NAME));
    holder.tv_department.setText(empHashmap.get(position).get(KEY_DEPARTMENT));

    return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_id, tv_name, tv_department;
}
```

}

Comment: cause you have only one entry in array.

Comment: please show whole error log, so i can show you where exactly error is eccor.

Comment: the problem could be in your BinderDataIdEmp or parser .only the stacktrace can help you figure where the problem is exactly. paste the entire stacktrace or error log like Jaydeep told you

Comment: @Jaydeep Patel and Steveen Zolenk: I was update logcat and BinderDataIdEmp  in my question

Comment: what is 71 line of IdEmp.java? @ 1234abcd

Comment: @Jaydeep Patel : line 71 of Idemp.java is "age_detail = empdetailHashmap.get(position).get(KEY_DETAIL_AGE);"

Comment: print your empdetailHashmap.size() this value is only 1 that's y it is happening., i think you are using  empdetailHashmap instead of empdetailList , try using  "age_detail = empdetailList .get(position).get(KEY_DETAIL_AGE);" @1234abcd

Comment: i was try, but it show "cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.string)' " in get(KEY_DETAIL_AGE);"